# Choropleth Plot not showing on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, plotly, choropleth

Getting no output when running choropleth maps in VS code, just getting a blank screen, happening recently after the latest vs code update.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True) 

data = dict
[enter image description here][1](
type = 'choropleth',
colorscale = 'Viridis',
locations = df['State Abv'],
reversescale = True,
locationmode = 'USA-states',
z = df['Voting-Age Population (VAP)'],
text = df['State'],
colorbar = {'title' : 'Voting-Age Population (VAP) per state'}
)

layout = dict(title = 'Voting-Age Population (VAP) per state',
        geo = dict(scope = 'usa', showlakes = True, lakecolor = 'rgb(85,173,240)'))

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data],layout = layout)
iplot(choromap,validate=False)
```

Added the link to the output below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWaOb.png

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, it was solved by adding a "renderer" parameter in the "show" method

fig.show(renderer='notebook')